# Bash : Check if PID exists with further logic

Tags: bash, if-statement, centos, pid

**Question:** How do you check if a PID exists and use the result within an IF statement in bash?

**Things I've tried**

```
if [ "$(ps -p $pid)" -eq 0 ]; then 
 echo "Running"
else
 echo "Not Running"
fi
```

---

```
if [ "$(kill -0 $pid)" -eq 0 ]; then 
 echo "Running"
else
 echo "Not Running"
fi
```

**Neither of these evaluate correctly no matter how I redirect STDOUT/STDER**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do you check if a PID exists and use the result within an if statement?

You can capture the output in a variable and then check the exit status:

```
output=$(ps -p "$pid")
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Found"
  echo "$output"
fi
```

Just remember that `$?` is getting reset every time you run a command, so something like the following wont work:

```
output=$(ps -p "$pid")
echo "$output"
# Now $? will be refering to the exit status of echo
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Found"
fi
```

One can also stick everything together in the if statement:

```
if output=$(ps -p "$pid")
then
  echo "Found: $output"
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Make it dynamic by passing the pid you want to check:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

if ps -p $1 > /dev/null;
then
echo "running"
else
echo "not running"
fi
```

Example runs:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What's your host OS?

If you have */proc* then this may work for you:

```
   if [ -d "/proc/$pid" ]; then
      echo "Running"
   else
      echo "Not running"
   fi
```

Comment: Targeted Centos 6.5-6.7